# Can I replace an attribute of a class?

Tags: acumatica

In the Sales Order screen, there is this view :

```
public PXSelect<SiteStatus> sitestatusview;
```

And SiteStatus table is declared as this :

```
[SiteStatusAccumulator]
[PXDisableCloneAttributes()]
[Serializable]
public partial class SiteStatus : INSiteStatus, IQtyAllocated
{...

...}
```

SiteStatusAccumulator among its usage is to check available quantities. And I want to override this validation. Particularly the SiteStatusAccumulator.PersistInserted method. With fields, I can cache_attached and override the attributes. But with tables, how can you achieve something similar ?